# How can I check if a branch name contains a Jira issue with a Bash regexp?

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I've got a variable in my shell script for a git branch name, that might contain a Jira issue key. I want to extract the issue from the variable if it matches my regexp.

A Jira issue can be some letters, followed by a dash, followed by some numbers. My script for this is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "pre-receive HOOK"

while read oldrev newrev refname
do
    echo "Refname is"
    echo $refname //refs/heads/XS-1141

    echo "Old revision is"
    echo $oldrev

    echo "New revision is"
    echo $newrev

    re="[A-Z]+-\d+"
    echo "checking if branch name contains a JIRA issue (format XX-1111, SRS-1 or similar)"
    if [[ $refname =~ $re ]]; then echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}; fi;
done
```

My input is in the comment there in the script (refs/heads/XS-1141) and the output of that is the BASH_REMATCH empty.

I'd like to achieve two things here:

1. Find out if the branch name contains a Jira issue
2. Extract that Jira issue to a variable

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your re has no groups, so you need to use `${BASH_REMATCH[0]}`

Also, you need to replace `\d` with `[0-9]` as `\d` digit matching pattern is not supported by POSIX ERE.

So you can use

```bash
#!/bin/bash
refname='refs/heads/XS-1141'
re="[A-Z]+-[0-9]+"
echo "checking if branch name contains a JIRA issue (format XX-1111, SRS-1 or similar)"
if [[ $refname =~ $re ]]; then echo ${BASH_REMATCH[0]}; fi;
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/grQiEN).

The `${BASH_REMATCH[0]}` holds the `XS-1141` value here.